# CSRF token is missing error even though it appears in template - Flask and pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest, flask-wtforms

I am working with a flask app and writing unit tests in pytest. I have a LoginForm (flaskwtf) that just takes a username and password string. When I run the app and log in through the form, everything works fine. But when I try to simulate a login with pytest, I get a CSRF is Missing error even thought the csrf is shown by {{ form.hidden_tag() }} in my template. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a flask app structured more or less like this:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import redirect
from flask import render_template_string
from flask import url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from wtforms import PasswordField
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms import SubmitField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'deadbeef'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username')
    password = PasswordField('Password')
    submit = SubmitField('submit')

TEMPLATE = '''\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <form>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}
            {{ form.username() }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}
            {{ form.password() }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
'''

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index() -> str:
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template_string(TEMPLATE, form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For testing flask apps, there is special test client as described in the [testing flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/#fixtures) docs, I am also assuming you are using this. With Flask-WTF there is an option called: `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` ([docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/config/?highlight=WTF_CSRF_ENABLED#configuration)) which you can use to turn off the CSRF-Protection.

It is common to switch this off for testing to make it easier. You can do this by setting `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED` to `False` in your test client's app-config:

```py
app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
```

A test with it switched off can look like this and passes without a missing CSRF-token error:

```py
import pytest

from t import app  # your app instance from the other file


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


def test_login(client):
    rv = client.post(
        '/',
        data={'username': 'test', 'password': 'test'},
        follow_redirects=True,
    )
    assert rv.status_code == 200
```

Answer (score 0):

During testing, you may want to disable CSRF or extract it during a GET request and add it to the form submission. Either way, the application will accept the form. A more practical approach, especially during testing, would be to disable CSRF as mentioned by @jkittner above.

```py
import unittest
from app import create_app      # using blueprints/factory function
from flask import current_app


class TestWebApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app

        # Form submission
        self.app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
        self.app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        # End

        self.app_ctxt = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_ctxt.push()
        db.create_all()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
```

Then, you can test user login.

```py
class TestWebApp(unittest.TestCase):
    
    # ...

    def test_user_login(self):
        response = self.client.post('/login', data={
            'username': 'user',
            'password': 'user'
        }, follow_redirects=True)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.request.path == '/profile'
```